# Node Express auth status

Tags: node.js, authentication, express

I have multiple routes, split into different files (my app consists of different "modules", which I maintain in separate folders. For each folder, there is an index.js file in which I manage the routes per module, and I require these in the app.js file).
For every route, I will require to check the auth, and pass the loggedIn status to the header of every page:

```
//Default variables for the ejs template 
var options = { 
    loggedIn: true
}; 

res.render("home/home", options);
```

If the logged in status is true, then the user's name will be displayed. If not, the login / signup labels are displayed.

What is the best way to centralise this, so that I don't need to require the auth script in every of these index.js (route) files?
I need to be able to pass the auth status to the view via the options object (see example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your auth, module, use a middleware function. That function can check and store `res.locals.loggedIn` which will be available for any view that will eventually be rendered. Just make sure the `app.use` call executes prior to your other routes and it will work properly.

```
app.use(function auth(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.loggedIn = true; // compute proper value here
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you need to do this for every request.One common thing is adding this as middleware so that all the request gets this .

For Example :

```
  var http = require('http');
  var connect = require('connect');
  var app = connect();
  app.use(function(req, res) {
     res.end('Hello!');
  });

  http.createServer(app).listen(3000)
```

Now for every request , Hello is printed . You could extract this as a module and reuse it across projects. Check [here](http://www.hacksparrow.com/how-to-write-midddleware-for-connect-express-js.html) for more details